# How to convert string to date with calculation?

Tags: python

I got after parsing date block (5 hours ago) or (14 minutes ago).

How can i get a date like: 01.21.21 3:31, i don't know how to get date with data like this.

Comment: Can you add a more detailed example of your input?

Comment: I have a list of dates: 1)5 minutes ago, 2) 7 hours ago, 3) 51 seconds ago and etc, no more than 24 hours. Is it possible to convers to date like 01.21.21 3:31?

Comment: So, they are referred to a specific moment in time: what it is? You must know it, otherwise anytime you run the script, you get different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's an unusual structure for incoming date data, but I would suggest trying out something like the following:

```
# import the requisite modules
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# sample string, you could loop through the data you have
date = "5 hours ago"

# splits the string into words (this assumes a predictable pattern in data)
words = date.split(" ")

# conditional logic to determine the right amount of time to subtract
if words[1] == 'hours':
  date = datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=int(words[0]))
elif words[1] == 'minutes':
  date = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=int(words[0]))

# print(date)
# 2021-01-20 17:05:08.161174
```

Hope this helps!  Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Every time you run this script you get different results, even with the same input. Maybe `datetime.now()` should be changed with a reference timestamp.